# Coded UI not working for latest Chrome browser version 54

Tags: visual-studio-2013, selenium-chromedriver, coded-ui-tests

After my Chrome browser updated to version 54 all my Coded UI tests are returning the following error. I have updated the chromedriver to 2.25 and 'selenium-dotnet-strongnamed' assemblies to 3.0.0. But still it did not work. I found that the webdriver classes are working fine, but Coded UI scripts are not working.

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

---

*Result Message: 
Test method CodedUIVthSelenium.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: windowHandle
Result StackTrace: 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(IntPtr windowHandle)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.InitializeTopLevelWindow()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.InitializeCrossBrowserService(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.<.cctor>b__0(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.Launch(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserFactory.Launch(String[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.LaunchPrivate(String[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.<>c__DisplayClass18.b__17()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.Launch(String[] arguments)
   at CodedUIVthSelenium.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() in e:\Praveen\CUIT\SampleProjects\CodedUIVthSelenium\CodedUITest1.cs:line 31*

Answer (score 1):

There is known issue that latest chrome version is not compatible with Coded UI. To bring your stuff in workable mode, you have to go down with chrome version. Following link will help you out with that:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/UFSYuIr1-80

/Hafiz